# How to implement MVVM in Xamarin.Forms with SQLite to populate a Listview who need INotifyPropertyChanged/Icommand in each row

Tags: sqlite, listview, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have my model A with some properties, i receive data from REST web service i use SQlite for local caching. With SQLite api i can use mi class A to automatically create tables and after retrieve data. Thats Ok

Now i need to get those data as a list to populate a listview, like a Todo-Item with a check (done - not done) to update a boolean every time user tap the "nice check image" so i need INotifyPropertyChanged by row

My option i think are:

1) Retrieve the whole list with SQlite api i will get a list. But i dont have INotifyPropertyChanged changes here. So i should convert the whole List to List who will have INotifyPropertyChanged and ICommand implemented. This will add extra process. but i think is the better i got

2) Inherit ViewModel directly from Model so i could achieve retrieve List directly from SQLite.net, but i should do another method in sqlite client for this specficic way to retrieve. and i will be accessing to SQLite from Model and ViewModel too, i think this should not be do it in this way

3) Add INotifyPropertyChanged and ICommand to the model...

i try approach to these 3 way but i really dont like the resulting code.
is there another way to do it or suggestion to improve the current options pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way out in your case would be to create a `ViewModel` for a list item, which would be implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and contain `ICommand` fields, and initialize it with data from a `Model` (whether through `ctor` or by creating a `factory`). This way you'll get a list of `ViewModel`s implementing all required features.
This is a pretty common approach.

Comment: so for retrieving items the right approach will be from the ViewModel of the Page, call SQLite client where i will receive a List<ItemModel> and right after convert to List<ItemViewModel>.I see it with a ListItemViewModel class where i can implement the list INotifyPropertyChanged too also parse every ItemModel to ItemViewModel...and next step populate ListView right? Are you agreed with this?

Comment: @RicardoAlvarezCastillo, I totally agree with the part where you convert a `List<ItemModel>` to `List<ItemViewModel>`. Typically this is done with `Factory` class having `ItemViewModel Convert(ItemModel)` method.

Comment: @RicardoAlvarezCastillo, maybe I am missing something? Why do you want the `List` to be implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`? It should be `ItemViewModel` who implements it.

Comment: You are right my main issue is ItemViewModel detail update. But if i want to update the list...i will be monitoring changes on REST data source and i could detect new items to include in the list (i could start the app with local store data, and when remote data is available update the list with changes. Should be new item, never less than current). I can do both INotifyPropertyChanged right?

Comment: @RicardoAlvarezCastillo, I guess what you are looking for is `ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>`. It implements both `INotifyPropertyChanged` (to notify about `Count` or `Item[]` change) and `ICollectionChanged` (to notify view about new items being added or existing items being removed).